# How can i get multiple data into a variable from select/option in php?

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-select

I want to get the answers into a variable `$cv = "Option 1,Option 2,Option 3"` assuming i selected first 3 options.

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <select name="ary[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    $values = $_POST['ary'];

    foreach ($values as $a){
        echo $a;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for implode function

$cv = implode(',', $values);